# Warum hat das deutsche Wort "Suggestion" eine ganz andere Bedeutung als das englische "Suggestion"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, english

Laut Duden trägt *Suggestion* die Bedeutung:

> geistig-psychische Beeinflussung eines Menschen [mit dem Ziel, ihn zu einem bestimmten Verhalten zu veranlassen]

Obwohl das englische Wort "suggestion" soviel wie *Vorschlag* bedeutet.

Warum ist es so, dass die Bedeutungen so unterschiedlich sind?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/suggestion#etymonline_v_22321

Comment: Bei ihrer jetzigen Form habe ich Zweifel, ob die Frage *on topic* ist. Die Pauschalantwort auf *warum* lautet ja *weil andere Sprecher das Wort so gebraucht haben*. Was sie sich dabei gedacht haben, wissen wir i.d.R. nicht. Zudem ist die Etymologie des englischen Begriffs sowie der Vergleich der beiden definitiv *off-topic* und ein Fall für English Language bzw. Linguistics SE. Des Weiteren scheint die Prämisse der ganzen Frage zu sein, dass Lehnwörter in beiden Sprachen die gleiche Bedeutung haben müssten – was aber auch kein Naturgesetz ist, von dem Abweichungen begründet sein müssten.

Comment: Da ohne die *off-topic*-Elemente (also ohne die englische Etymologie und den Vergleich der beiden) nur noch die Frage nach der deutschen Etymologie übrig bleiben würde und diese durch ein etymologisches Wörterbuch beantwortet werden kann, stimme ich dafür, die Frage zu schließen – jedoch mit der ausdrücklichen Empfehlung, sie ggf. bei Linguistics SE oder (vgl. den Tag *english*) bei English Language SE zu stellen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Bedeutungen ähneln sich sehr, auch ein Vorschlag kann eine »Beeinflussung eines Menschen [mit dem Ziel ...« sein.

Im Englischen kann *suggestion* auch die gleiche Bedeutung haben, wie Du sie für »Suggestion« im Deutschen zitierst, nämlich

> putting an idea into people’s minds by connecting it with other ideas

Quelle: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/suggestion?q=suggestion , Nr. 3

Answer (score -1):

Wie das zugehörige Verb *suggerieren* sich geriet, führt es den indikativen Wortstamm fort, den Englisch nicht kennt (während Englisch entweder eine Rückformation vom Nomen *Suggestion* vorführt, vgl. Lat. *suggestum*, oder auch vom supine Stamm ableitet; WT nennt die Form eine Ummünzung, "coined", ohne den Urheber zu nennen, mag dahinstehen).

Im Deutschen könnte zudem eine Verbanung mit dem heute raren Verb *gerieren* in Frage kommen, das sonst nur noch reflexiv im Konjunktiv (*sich geriet*) in Erzählform Verwendung findet, bzw. davon scheinbar abgekommen *geraten* (das dann wiederum in Idiomen wie *auf's Geratewohl* mit *raten*, aber das führt an dieser Stelle sicherlich zu weit). Dies ist selbst von Latein *se gerere* "to behave", und zwar von des gleichen Wort Stamm wie *suggere*.

Mir scheint demnach so, es lagen zwei zum Verwechseln ähnliche Formen zu Grunde, die dann und wann auch noch verwechselt werden.